# Acces Point unavailable by ICMP Ping Zabbix Monitoring

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

Using Zabbix 4.2 I detect that a device, more specifically, an Access Point, shows an alert saying that, the mentioned device is unavailable by ICMP Ping.

Does this mean that the mentioned device is offline or that it has been turned off?

Comment: you can't know, of course. if ICMP ping doesn't work, can be turned off, or an issue on any hop in between zabbix and the device

Comment: Okey, thank you very much. Have a nice day!